# Does an einzel lens draw current?

Tags: electrostatics, accelerator-physics

I was trying to think about the physics of a single particle in an [Einzel lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einzel_lens).  As it enters the lens, it would draw negative current, and then as it leaves the lens, it would draw positive current.  If you have a steady state current, both these effects are happening simultaneously, so would the net current draw be 0?

Answer (score -1):

Particles moving through an Einzel lens do not gain or lose energy. This can be seen by considering the symmetry of the system about the central element of the lens. A consequence of the symmetry is that the electric potential is also symmetric and so a particle coming from $z=-\infty$ leaves with the same potential as at $z=\infty$. The energy change is $\Delta E = V(z=\infty) - V(z=-\infty) = 0$.

Since the particles gain no energy, the net energy change in the electrical system is also zero. The net energy change can be written as $\Delta E = \int P(t)\mathrm{d}t = \int V \cdot I(t)\mathrm{d}t = 0$, where $P(t)$ is the lens's power, $V$ the voltage, and $I(t)$ is the current. This makes the time averaged current ($\int I(t) \mathrm{d}t$) zero.